# My DELETE method doesn't work from a Submit Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Im trying to get a DELETE request working but it concat's to this:
"http://localhost:3000/users/delete?userid=593d774c734d1d02258f5315"
it doesnt go trough my app.js listener I have a console log.
This is my code.
(Oh and Im trying to get it to work with no ajax.

This is the HTML(with ejs):

```
<form method="DELETE" action="/users/delete">
    <input type="hidden" value="<%= users[i]._id %>" name="userid">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And this is the Listener:

`app.delete('/users/delete',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
})`

What I do know that the ejs function works as you can see its being passed in the url and Ive tried printing it inside the html.

Comment: HTTP DELETE is supported in XMLHttpRequest by most browsers, but may not be supported for straight form posts, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/166501/8085849

Comment: So I need to change it to a POST method? Or use ajax.

Comment: If you're able to use an XMLHttpRequest instead then that should work; otherwise, switch to a POST request.